# CSS issue in the registration form while making custom input fields

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm trying to make a custom input field using HTML and CSS. The input field looks fine on the PC, as you can see on the first picture:

[image]

However, on the small screens, country field looks bigger than others:

[image]

This is the HTML code (for simplicity I will only use code for city and for country):

```
           <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <span class="form-relative">
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" class="clean-slide" id="city" th:field="*{city}"
                                   required="required" maxlength="45" minlength="2"/>
                            <label for="city">City</label>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <span class="form-relative">
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <select class="clean-slide" th:field="*{country}" id="country">
                                <th:block th:each="country : ${listCountries}">
                                <option th:value="${country.countryId}">[[${country.name}]]</option>
                                </th:block>
                            </select>
                            <label for="country">Country</label>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

As you can see, the code is not the same, and I'm using `clean-slide` class from CSS:

```
.clean-slide {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 90px;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #377D6A;
    background: #efefef;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 3px;
    outline: 0;
    text-indent: 60px;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.clean-slide::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #efefef;
    text-indent: 0;
    font-weight: 300;
}
.clean-slide + label {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(0);
    top: 0;
    left: auto;
    bottom: -8px;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #032429;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out, color .3s ease-out;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.clean-slide + label:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #0c9669;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: translate(0);
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}

.clean-slide:focus,
.clean-slide:active {
    color: #377D6A;
    text-indent: 0;
    background: #fff;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.clean-slide:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.clean-slide:active::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #aaa;
}
.clean-slide:focus + label,
.clean-slide:active + label {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(19, 74, 70, 0.4);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.clean-slide:focus + label:after,
.clean-slide:active + label:after {
    transform: translate(100%);
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .clean-slide {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .form-group.row label[for] {
        position: absolute;
        left: 15px;
        top: 12px;
        font-size: 12px;
        padding: 2px 5px;
        padding-left: 30px;
        padding-right: 30px;
    }
}
```

It seems that this `<option>` (or `<select>`) element is causing this weird behavior. How can I solve this problem?

Note: I'm using the Bootstrap also.

Comment: Are you also using Bootstrap?

Comment: Yes, I'm using boostrap here. Actually all of the CSS classes in my HTML code here are from the boostrap (excluding only clean-slide).

Comment: It has its own responsive styling, that may be part of the problem.

Comment: Yeah, you are in right. I'm going to edit the question to add this information (which is actually very important). However, this is still weird to me, since other fields are just fine. Only the one with dropdown is causing the problem.

Comment: @nikolaPantelic98, I think your pb comes from your clean-slide css class, in particular from padding: 10px 0 10px 90px (90px is the pb)

Comment: Something other than HTML /  CSS / Bootstrap is going on here, what is `<th:block></th>` ? That certainly isn't regular HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some tips when making responsive design:
Try not to use fixed values like those who are in px,
If you have for example a input dont make width and height using fixed values and avoid as much as you can the height instead make the font size of the input using clamp() and add padding with em because em is based on font size so if you make font size responsive using clamp() the input will also be responsive because its height by default is auto and when you use padding the height will increase based on font size.And for the width i personally use mostly % wich means the percentage of the container and the container i can make it the % of screen and set a max-width property to it an example code below:

**Html**

```
 <body>
<div class="container">
<input type="text"/>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
html{
width:100%;
}
body{
width:100%;
}
.container{
wdith:70%;
max-width: 300px;
}
.container input{
font-size: clamp(1rem, 2vw, 3.5rem);
padding:0.5em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it's very helpful since I'm backend developer and currently I'm trying to make fullstack apps. Thanks.